# Question related to https://oeis.org/A051708

Tags: sequences-and-series

This question relates to
https://oeis.org/A051708

The question is wether priorly submitted and accepted into A051708 formula by Vladimir Kruchinin

$$Sum[Binomial[n - 1, n - i] Sum[Binomial[k + i, i] Binomial[n - 1, n - k], {k, 0, n}], {i, 0, n}]$$

= ?

$$(-1)^n*((-4*n^2 - 16*n - 28)*JacobiP[-1 + n, -1 - 2*n, 2, -1/2] + JacobiP[-2 + n, -2*n, 3, -1/2]*(3 + n)*(-1 + n))*4^n/(48*(1 + n)*n)$$

which was resently submitted and rejected (as unsubstantiated) by Mariusz Iwaniuk

In the standard scientific notation above sums expression looks like following:

$$ Sum_{i=0..n} (C(n-1,n-i)*Sum_{k=0..n} (C(k+i,i)*C(n-1,n-k))) $$

Please note that numerically Mathematica seems to be confirming that both expressions give the same numerical values per following:

Table[ (-1)^n*((-4*n^2 - 16*n - 28)*JacobiP(-1 + n, -1 - 2*n, 2, -1/2) + JacobiP(-2 + n, -2*n, 3, -1/2)*(3 + n)*(-1 + n))*4^n/(48*(1 + n)*n), {n, 1, 15}]
{2,14,106,838,6802,56190,470010,3968310,33747490,288654574,2480593546,21400729382,185239360178,1607913963614,13991107041306}

Table[Sum[Binomial[n - 1, n - i] Sum[Binomial[k + i, i] Binomial[n - 1, n - k], {k, 0, n}], {i, 0, n}], {n, 1, 15}]
{2,14,106,838,6802,56190,470010,3968310,33747490,288654574,2480593546,21400729382,185239360178,1607913963614,13991107041306}

but there's a need in a symbolic proof.

Comment: It would be better to Use Mathjax

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to report that the problem is solved in Mathematica by Christoph Koutschan by using his add-on package "HolonomicFunctions" (https://www3.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/ergosum/RISC/HolonomicFunctions.html).

The problem is solved by computing recurrences for both expressions and showing that they coincide.

Wolframalpha confirms that the recurrence obtained by Christoph Koutschan for both expressions

f[1]=2, f[2]=14, 9*n*f[n] + (-14 - 10*n)*f[1 + n] + (2 + n)*f[2 + n] == 0

gives
n | f(n)

1 | 2

2 | 14

3 | 106

4 | 838

5 | 6802

6 | 56190

7 | 470010

...

which are correct values for
https://oeis.org/A051708

So as the conclusion it follows that both:

the formula obtained byMariusz Iwaniuk
$$(-1)^n*((-4*n^2 - 16*n - 28)*JacobiP[-1 + n, -1 - 2*n, 2, -1/2] + JacobiP[-2 + n, -2*n, 3, -1/2]*(3 + n)*(-1 + n))*4^n/(48*(1 + n)*n)$$

and the recurrence obtained by Christoph Koutschan

$$ f[1]=2, f[2]=14, 9*n*f[n] + (-14 - 10*n)*f[1 + n] + (2 + n)*f[2 + n] == 0$$

rightfully belong to
https://oeis.org/A051708

Thanks ,
Best Regards,
Alexander R Povolotsky